# How to install freeipa server with apache ssl/tls virtualhosts already present

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, apache-2.4, installation, freeipa

**Is it possible to run an FreeIPA server next to a full configured apache server with ssl/tls configured virtual hosts and if yes what do I have to do to not get a conflicting 443 port error during installation?**

Background: On a CentOS 7.1 machine I have installed apache with multiple virtual hosts which support SSL/TLS encryption. Now I want to install a FreeIPA server on this system. But when running the command *ipa-server-install* I get following error message:

```
Apache is already configured with a listener on port 443:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
ipa.ipapython.install.cli.install_tool(Server): ERROR    Aborting installation
```

Comment: Don't do this. Your domain controller should not have random third party services running on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeIPA installer is not designed to be run on the machine where apache already serves something else.

NOTE: Your FreeIPA master server is equal to the heart of your internal infrastructure as it hosts your key components -- passwords are there, as well as key private certificates that can be used to compromise your whole environment if not secured properly. Running third-party apps at the heart of your infrastructure is increasing attack surface and simply making it more vulnerable to external attacks -- you now would need to make sure your third-party apps secure enough.

Answer (score -2):

Change the port for apache to 444 , run the install, then change it back.If the apache sserver is in a live environment and you dont want to take it down,forward port 443 to 444

Comment: FreeIPA installer is not designed to be run on the machine where apache already serves something else. More to that, your FreeIPA master server is equal to the heart of your internal infrastructure as it hosts your key components -- passwords are there, as well as key private certificates that can be used to compromise your whole environment if not secured properly.

Running third-party apps at the heart of your infrastructure is increasing attack surface and simply making it more vulnerable to external attacks -- you now would need to make sure your third-party apps secure enough.

Comment: @abbra I find this a great answer could you post this as an answer

Comment: @elhombre reposted.